# Setting DisplayMemberPath of ComboBox in code

Tags: wpf-controls

In my WPF program I have:

```
        string queryString = "Select AccountID, ProjectName from Foo where IsEnabled = 1";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, sConn1);
        DataSet dsAccounts = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dsAccounts, "Accounts");

        cbAccount.ItemsSource = dsAccounts.Tables["Accounts"].AsEnumerable();
        cbAccount.DisplayMemberPath = "ProjectName";
```

When my program runs and I dropdown the ComboBox all the rows are there but they display as blanks. When I click on a row, my SelectionChanged event handler properly identifies the selected row and picks up the proper values.

I believe my problem is with the DisplayMemberPath.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but rather a workaround. This works:

```
        cbAccount.DataContext = dsAccounts.Tables["Accounts"];
        //cbAccount.ItemsSource = dsAccounts.Tables["Accounts"].AsEnumerable();
        cbAccount.DisplayMemberPath = "ProjectName";
```

By setting the DataContext reather than the ItemSource then the DisplayMemberPath is being set properly.

The question remains open, there must be a way to properly set the DisplayMemberPath when one has an ItemSource rather than a DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your table accounts is not serialized to objects.

If you use a list of accounts instead of your tables then it works perfect with the ItemsSource and DisplayMemeberPath.